# onclick close modal and open popup

Tags: javascript

We have a Modal Window with a contact form within it.

We have two buttons at the bottom, of the form.

One of which on click opens a separate live chat window ( not modal )

So my issue is onclick of the button ( on the modal window ) I want to open the popup window, ( which we have fully working ) but simultaneously, close the modal window. As it is not needed.

The link code is:

```
<a href="<?=curPageURL();?>#" onclick="javascript:launchSupport('https://www.somesite.com.au/livechat/chat.php', '200', '200', '510', '440');jQuery.lightbox().close();"><span class="newSamplePromo">Live Chat</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're already using jQuery, just give that `<a>` tag an ID and then assign a click handler for it using jQuery.

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery("#liveChatLink").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    launchSupport('https://www.somesite.com.au/livechat/chat.php', '200', '200', '510', '440');
    jQuery.lightbox().close();
  });
});


<a id="liveChatLink" href="<?=curPageURL();?>#"><span class="newSamplePromo">Live Chat</span></a>
```

Comment: Hmm didnt work.
I have added the jQuery on the page. just wrapped in script tags, is that right ?

Comment: Are you getting javascript errors? If so, can you share them?

Comment: No, our jquery lightbox function is: 
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery('.lightbox').lightbox();
    });